# Get reference dll into another dll which is exposed to COM

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, com

I'm want to find the answers for this problem:

I'm developing a .NET 4.0 DLL wich has reference to another third party Dll FTP. This DLL that i'm developing is loaded through reflection  by another DLL called LoaderDLLs.

LoaderDLLs is exposed for COM, the problem is when the COM use DLL to invoke .NET DLL 4.0 everything is fine but when .NET DLL 4.0  internally call third party DLL FTP occurs next error:

**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.Could not load file or assembly 'Jscape.Ssh, Version=2.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have attemped install third party DLL FTP into GAC through gacutil, but a think this is not working, How can i get reference to that DLL?

Comment: To start with, try putting all your dlls/assemblies in the same folder.

Comment: The CLR isn't going to be able to find it, it looks in the directory of the COM client program for the assembly.  You really do need to get it into the GAC.  Won't work with a null PublicKeyToken, it has to be strong named.  Implementing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event in your [ComVisible] assembly could be a workaround, it is not a pretty one.

Comment: Thanks, for your recomendations, finally , i have been using refletion to use FTP dll inside of my .NET DLL 4.0, because to  my team is no permitted to install in the GAC in production enviroment. Thanks =)